# How to use inline regex modifier in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex:

```
(.*\n)+DOCUMENTATION.*(\"\"\"|''')\n-*\n?((.*\n)+?)(\2)(?s:.*)
```

witch I'm trying to process some files like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# <GNU license here>

DOCUMENTATION = """
module: foo
short_description: baz
<some more here>    
"""

<rest of the python code>
```

I need to get the DOCUMENTATION part from it.

It work quite well but not with python. The problem is with inline modifier `?s:.*` which I used to catch rest of the file (any character including new-line zero or more times). Looks that it's somehow different in python.

Here at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rR0uO1/1) is the example. It shows an error when I switch it to python.

**NOTE:** I can't set modifiers globally. (I can only pass regex rule to some python module).

Comment: For some reason `(.*\n)+` as I used at the begging of the regex doesn't catch everything. BTW: I read somewhere that the Python might not support that. If it's true than I will appreciate any other solution for the main problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Inline Modifiers in the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Python implements **[inline (embedded) modifiers](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags)**, such as `(?s)`, `(?i)` or `(?aiLmsux)`, but not as part of a non-capturing group modifier like you were trying to use.
`(?smi:subpattern)` works in Perl and PCRE, but not in Python.

Moreover, using an inline modifier anywhere in the pattern **applies to the whole match** and it can't be turned off.

> **[From regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html):**
>   In Python, putting a modifier in the middle of the regex affects the
>   whole regex. So in Python, <kbd>`(?i)caseless`</kbd> and <kbd>`caseless(?i)`</kbd> are both case
>   insensitive.

---

**Example:**

```python
import re

text = "A\nB"
print("Text: '%s'\n---" % text)
patterns = [ "a", "a(?i)", "A.*B", "A(?s).*B", "A.*(?s)B"]

for p in patterns:
    match = re.search( p, text)
    print("Pattern: '%s'    \tMatch: %s" % (p, match.span() if match else None))
```

**Output:**

```
Text: 'A
B'
---
Pattern: 'a'            Match: None
Pattern: 'a(?i)'        Match: (0, 1)
Pattern: 'A.*B'         Match: None
Pattern: 'A(?s).*B'     Match: (0, 3)
Pattern: 'A.*(?s)B'     Match: (0, 3)
```

<kbd>[ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/7AAuaK)</kbd>

---

#### Solution

`(?s)` (aka *singleline* or `re.DOTALL`) makes **`.`** also match newlines. And since you're trying to set it to only a part of the pattern, there are 2 alternatives:

1. **Match anything except newlines**:
   Set `(?s)` for the whole pattern (either passed as flag or inline), and use **`[^\n]*`** instead of a dot, to match any characters except newlines.
2. **Match everything including newlines**:
   Use **`[\S\s]*`** instead of a dot, to match any characters including newlines. The character class includes all whitespace and all that is not a whitespace (thus, all characters).

For the specific case you presented, you can use the following expression:

```
(?m)^DOCUMENTATION.*(\"{3}|'{3})\n-*\n?([\s\S]+?)^\1[\s\S]*
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rR0uO1/2)</kbd>

---

<sub>**Note:** This post covers inline modifiers in the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), whereas [Matthew Barnett's regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) does in fact implement inline modifiers (scoped flags) with the same behaviour observed in PCRE and Perl.</sub>