# re.search() and re.findall() are hanging

Tags: python, regex

I'm having an issue when using re.search() or re.findall(). But let me explain first. I'm searching through C-Code, which contains definitions like this:

```c
#define SOME_FUNCTION( someArgument, someMoreArgument)
```

Sometimes, when they have a lots of arguments, they are wrapped, so they look like this:

```c
#define ANOTHER_FUNCTION( moreArgument, evenMoreArguments,
                          anAwfulLotOfArguments, youGetIt)
```

Now I'm using python to scan through these files to find every single one of these definitions. My regex looks like follows:

```
#define [A-Z,_]*\((?:.|\s)+?\"
```

When testing this with single- and multiline definitions in testing engines like [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) it works flawlessly.

However, when I use this with python (3.4.1), it only works for single-lined definitions. When it tries to scan multiline definitions, it just stops executing (although I can interrupt it with Ctrl + C). I tried using :

```
regexFullMacro = re.compile("#define [A-Z,_]*\((?:.|\s)+?\)")
match = regexFullMacro.search(searchString)
```

as well as

```
regexFullMacro = re.compile("#define [A-Z,_]*\((?:.|\s)+?\)")
match = regexFullMacro.findall(searchString)
```

where both tries just stop responding when it comes to multiple lines.

Has anyone had this issue before or am I just utterly stupid and missing something obvious?

Comment: When you test on regex101 are you using the full contents of a source file as sample? You probably have an issue with backtracking but this would not be noticeable if you only test with short strings...

Comment: An obvious thing is to NEVER use `(?:.|\s)+?` inside a regex pattern. It causes so heavy backtracking that the engine gets stuck. You always want `.` with a DOTALL modifier or `[\s\S]` when it is required to only apply this behavior for a part of the pattern. In this case, `"#define [A-Z,_]*\([^()]+\)"` should be enough since negated character class `[^()]` matches any char but `(` and `)` including newlines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Right . Use `[^)]+` instead in that place, this wont do any backtracking.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I used the solution provided by @WiktorStribiżew and it worked flawlessly. If I could ask for a favor, could you please describe a bit, what [^()]+ does better than (?:.|\s)+? and why that solution does not create any backtracking? That would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
r"#define [A-Z,_]*\([^()]+\)"
```

The negated character class `[^()]` matches any char but `(` and `)` (including newlines) and the `+` quantifier makes the regex engine match 1 or more consecutive occurrences of them.

**Root cause**

The `(?:.|\s)+?` inside a regex pattern (when there are other subpatterns to follow) causes too much expansion operations (it is a lazy pattern, and we can only talk about backtracking with greedy modifiers) that freezes the regex engine. The main problem with this alternation group is that `.` can match what `\s` matches. When alternations in a group can match at the same location, it is always a bottleneck as once one alternative fails, the other is tried and goes on trying many more times if the group is quantified (as here).

You always want `.` with a `DOTALL` modifier or `[\s\S]` instead when it is required to only apply this behavior for a part of the pattern (in Python `re`, the [`[\S\s]` workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312175/matching-any-character-including-newlines-in-a-python-regex-subexpression-not-g/33312193#33312193) is very helpful as [`re` does not support modifier groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353897/how-to-use-inline-regex-modifier-in-python)).